# laravel 5.6 how to get the number of msgs for all groups?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:
users, groups, messages;

user table is the default table generated by `php artisan make:auth`, Groups table contain:

id, book_id

messages table contain:

id, group_id, from, msg_content

and there is many to many relation between users table and groups table, the pivot table conatain:

user_id, group_id, last_id_seen

now I want to get the groups that belongs to the user and the number of messages that belongs to each group and have id > last_id_seen in the following form:

group => number_of_messages_>_last_id_seen

I am new to Laravel so would you please help me to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to write so far?

Comment: what do you store in `last_id_seen` ? do you store `message_id` in it ?

Comment: because I want to retrive non seen messages only

Comment: @thefallen I tried : $Groups=Auth::user()->groups()->get();
        $num=$Groups->reduce(function($sum, $Groups){
            $lsi=$Groups->pivot->last_id_seen;
            return $sum+$Groups->messages()->where('id','>', $lsi)->count();
        });
but it return nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$groups = Auth::user()->groups()->withCount(['messages' => function($query) {
    $query->whereColumn('id', '>', 'last_id_seen');
}])->get();

foreach($groups as $group) {
    // $group->messages_count
}
```